# TDM-GCC compiled win32x64 DLL cannot be loaded in python 3.6 but can when using python 2.7

Tags: python, winapi, dll, ctypes, tdm-gcc

#### my environment *console output of cmd.exe*

```
Microsoft Windows [10.0.15063.1112]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation

C:\Users\>py -3
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:54:40) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>

C:\Users\>py -2
Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:53:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
E:\TDM-GCC-64\bin>gcc --version
gcc (tdm64-1) 5.1.0
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

as below console output says, I'm using two versions of python. And I created a DLL project using Code::Blocks 16.01, which is using TDM-GCC of GNU GCC Compiler(the GNU GCC Compiler included in the codeblocks can't build x86_64 program, and x86 dll it built caused WindowsError:[Error 193] when loading using following code)

#### python code here (testdll.py)

```
import ctypes
DLL_PATH = './testdll.dll'
lib = ctypes.WinDLL(DLL_PATH) 
# or #lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(DLL_PATH) 
#didn't work in python3.6
print("dll loaded")
lib.SomeFunction(b"12345")
```

#### dll c++ code(mostly generated by codeblocks)

```
#include "main.h"
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

// a sample exported function
void DLL_EXPORT SomeFunction(const LPCSTR sometext)
{
    MessageBoxA(0, sometext, "DLL Message", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}

extern "C" DLL_EXPORT BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{

    volatile char* aaa = new char[100];
    switch (fdwReason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            // attach to process
            // return FALSE to fail DLL load
            break;

        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            // detach from process
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
            // attach to thread
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
            // detach from thread
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return TRUE; // succesful
}

char* bar(char* a, char* b)//the only function i added, which was copied from someone's blog
{
    char* out = new char[strlen(a) + strlen(b) + 1];
    strcpy(out, a);
    strcat(out, b);
    return out;
}
```

#### here are the main.h

```
#ifndef __MAIN_H__
#define __MAIN_H__

#include <windows.h>

/*  To use this exported function of dll, include this header
 *  in your project.
 */

#ifdef BUILD_DLL
    #define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

void DLL_EXPORT SomeFunction(const LPCSTR sometext);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif // __MAIN_H__
```

#### DLL compile options (build log)

```
-------------- Build: Release in testdll (compiler: TDM-GCC of GNU GCC Compiler)---------------
[ 50.0%] g++.exe -m64 -Wall -DBUILD_DLL -O2 -Wshadow -Winit-self -Winline -Wswitch-default -Wmain -Wfatal-errors -std=c++11 -g -Weffc++ -Wextra -Wall -Wno-comment -DLOCAL -IE:\TDM-GCC-64\include -c Y:\testdll\main.cpp -o obj\Release\main.o
[100.0%] g++.exe -shared -Wl,--output-def=bin\Release\libtestdll.def -Wl,--out-implib=bin\Release\libtestdll.a -Wl,--dll -LE:\TDM-GCC-64\lib obj\Release\main.o  -o bin\Release\testdll.dll -m64 -s  -luser32
```

#### problem

when using `py -2 testdll.py`, it works fine and got the message box and the console log 'dll loaded', but when
using `python -3 testdll.py`, here is the trace back.

```
Y:\testdll\bin\Release>py -3 testdll.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testdll.py", line 10, in <module>
    lib = ctypes.WinDLL(DLL_PATH)
  File "E:\Python36x64\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 1114]
```

and when I removed that function(the code below) from c++ code, click the rebuild button, rerun the python code using Python2 or Python3, it both works fine and got right output.

```
char* bar(char* a, char* b)//the only function i added, which was copied from someone
{
    char* out = new char[strlen(a) + strlen(b) + 1];// after some test, I think
                                                    // this line caused this problem
                                                    // using such as 
                                                    //volatile char *ppp=new char[66];
                                                    // will cause the dll file become 100kB+ larger and can't be loaded by Python 3.6 
                                                    // ##(some strange thing happens, when I rerun this, this function no longer matters, it can't be loaded by Python3.6 anyways)##
    strcpy(out, a);
    strcat(out, b);
    return out;
}
```

who can tell me why, thank you, I'm really confused.

#### I've just rerun these steps (using command line not codeblocks)

1, copy the code posted above (and saved somewhere)
2, open cmd.exe
3, run the following commands(and pasted the output here)

```
Y:\tmp>g++.exe -m64 -Wall -DBUILD_DLL -O2 -Wshadow -Winit-self -Winline -Wswitch-default -Wmain -Wfatal-errors -std=c++11 -g -Weffc++ -Wextra -Wall -Wno-comment -DLOCAL -IE:\TDM-GCC-64\include -c main.cpp -o main.o
main.cpp: In function 'BOOL DllMain(HINSTANCE, DWORD, LPVOID)':
main.cpp:15:20: warning: unused variable 'aaa' [-Wunused-variable]
     volatile char* aaa = new char[100];
                    ^
main.cpp: At global scope:
main.cpp:12:55: warning: unused parameter 'hinstDLL' [-Wunused-parameter]
 extern "C" DLL_EXPORT BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
                                                       ^
main.cpp:12:89: warning: unused parameter 'lpvReserved' [-Wunused-parameter]
 extern "C" DLL_EXPORT BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
                                                                                         ^

Y:\tmp>g++.exe -shared -Wl,--output-def=libtestdll.def -Wl,--out-implib=libtestdll.a -Wl,--dll -LE:\TDM-GCC-64\lib main.o  -o testdll.dll -m64 -s  -luser32
```

4, rerun py -3 testdll.py
and I still got OSError: [WinError 1114]
But this time, I removed that function which I mentioned above, Python3.6 still refuse to load that dll, :(

5, check `py -3` and `py -2` and `gcc --version`, confirmed that the version remains unchanged

#### my solution

While compile CodeBlocks generated projects to WinDll was unsuccessful; I tried to compile manually written sources to cdll to gain the native speed (but can't use some macros such as `DLL_EXPORT`)using commands below.

```
$(GCC) $< -o $@ -I $(SRC_DIR)/common/crapto1/ -Wl,crapto1.dll -shared
g++ test.cpp -o test.dll -shared
etc.
```

The code below compiled and loaded successfully by my g++ and py2, py3.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
extern "C" int foo();
int foo(){
  printf("This Works!\n");
  MessageBoxA(0, "This Works!", "DLL Message", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
  return 0;
}
//ctypes.WinDLL(DLL_PATH).foo()
//ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(DLL_PATH).foo() #both works fine in Python 2 and Python 3
```

Comment: Have you looked up what that error code means?

Comment: win error 1114 from link https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/desktop/Debug/system-error-codes--1000-1299- it said "A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed." and after Google that error code,some said that native dll may have error and need to be rebuilt.but in my case, that the same dll works fine with Python 2, which makes me confused.could U tell me if there is something wrong with the 
 code or the build options? thanks for your time

Comment: After a few changes (mainly `#define`s and adding `extern "C"` to `SomeFunction` - I don't know how it worked for you), and __building with *MinGW64*'s *g++*__, it worked with both *Python* versions.

Comment: I added the missing main.h(it includes some #define, it's totally automatically generated by CodeBlocks, so I thought it wasn't  important and forget to post it at first), using MinGW64 g++ works? I'll have a try, thank U, but I'm still concerned about why TDM-GCC didn't work, there must be a reason, either I make a mistake or I have a wrong configuration of my environment, and another reason is that I mainly 
use MinGW for another purpose(the tool chain is configured  for another platform).

Comment: It can't be. This **doesn't work** (and should not work). You're using other code than  what you've posted. Please edit the question and add the **correct** information.