# Accesing the referenced C struct string from python ctypes

Tags: c, string, pointers, struct, ctypes

I cannot access from python *ctypes* the (fixed length) *string* from referenced structure allocated by C code (dll library). But the *int* type I can access and change.

This is simplified code. In reality I'm accessing proprietary dll which I cannot change, therefore please take the content of this dll as fixed.
I'm able to access the dll struct string from C code without problems - that's the way I constructed this example dll, so it's interface is the same as interface of proprietary dll.

My assumption was that wrong is either python declaration of *"text"* in *DATA_STRUCT* (various tested possibilities are listed), or the way I want to access the string -  are commented as they are either returning only object or fails in windows error (access violation).

Just to note, I'm using compiler provided with Dev-C++ TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64-bit (which should use MingW64) and 64bit Python 3.8.2.
The reason for using 64 bit python is the proprietary dll, which is 64bit.
Everthing is under Windows (7).

**dll.h**

```
typedef struct REFERENCE_STRUCT {
    int     type ;
    void * dataP ;
} REFERENCE_STRUCT ;

typedef struct DATA_STRUCT {
    int        number ;
    char       text [41] ; // the string is fixed length
} DATA_STRUCT ;

__declspec(dllexport) int test_alloc (REFERENCE_STRUCT *refP) ;
__declspec(dllexport) int test_print (REFERENCE_STRUCT *refP) ;
__declspec(dllexport) int test_free (REFERENCE_STRUCT *refP) ;
```

**maindll.c**

```
#include "dll.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

__declspec(dllexport) int test_alloc (REFERENCE_STRUCT *refP) {
    DATA_STRUCT         *dataP ;
    dataP = malloc (sizeof (DATA_STRUCT));
    dataP->number = 5 ;
    strcpy (dataP->text, "number 1");
    refP->type = 40 ;
    refP->dataP = ( void *) dataP ;
    printf ("DLL - alloc: reference type: %d;  data <%d>; <%s>\n", refP->type, dataP->number, dataP->text) ;
    return 0;
} ;

__declspec(dllexport) int test_print (REFERENCE_STRUCT *refP) {
    DATA_STRUCT         *dataP ;
    dataP = (DATA_STRUCT*) refP->dataP ;
    printf ("DLL - print: reference type: %d;  data <%d>; <%s>\n", refP->type, dataP->number, dataP->text) ;
    return 0;
} ;

__declspec(dllexport) int test_free (REFERENCE_STRUCT *refP){
    free(refP->dataP) ;
    printf ("DLL - free\n") ;
    return 0;
} ;
```

**script.py**

```
import sys,os, ctypes, ctypes.util, faulthandler
faulthandler.enable()

os.add_dll_directory("D:/path_to_lib/")
mylib_path = ctypes.util.find_library("mydll")
mylib = ctypes.CDLL(mylib_path)

class REFERENCE_STRUCT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("type", ctypes.c_int),
               ("dataP", ctypes.c_void_p)]

class DATA_STRUCT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("number", ctypes.c_int),
                ("text", ctypes.c_char * (41))]    # !!! THIS declaration is correct for C "char       text [41] ;" !!!
                ("text", ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char * (41)))]    # WHICH declaration is correct for C "char       text [41] ;" ?
#                 ("text", ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char))]           # WHICH declaration is correct for C "char       text [41] ;" ?
#                 ("text", ctypes.c_char_p)]                         # WHICH declaration is correct for C "char       text [41] ;" ?

reference = REFERENCE_STRUCT()

print("test_alloc: ", mylib.test_alloc (ctypes.byref(reference)))
print("reference.type: ", reference.type)

dataP = ctypes.cast(reference.dataP, ctypes.POINTER(DATA_STRUCT))

# accessing the number without problem:

print("dataP.contents.number:      ",dataP.contents.number)
print(ctypes.cast(reference.dataP,         
ctypes.POINTER(DATA_STRUCT)).contents.text)
print("test_print: ", mylib.test_print (ctypes.byref(reference)))
dataP.contents.number = 7
ctypes.cast(reference.dataP, ctypes.POINTER(DATA_STRUCT)).contents.text = b'num 6'
print("dataP.contents.number:      ",dataP.contents.number)
print(ctypes.cast(reference.dataP, ctypes.POINTER(DATA_STRUCT)).contents.text)
print("test_print: ", mylib.test_print (ctypes.byref(reference)))
print("\n")

print("test_free: ", mylib.test_free (ctypes.byref(reference))) # freeing the alocated memory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listing [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

There are some problems:

1. *DATA_STRUCT.text* definition (as you noticed). It should be: **`("text", ctypes.c_char * 41)`**
2. ***argtypes*** and ***restype*** definitions for the foreign functions. Topic detailed in [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58610333/c-function-called-from-python-via-ctypes-returns-incorrect-value/58611011#58611011)
3. Accessing the member: `ctypes.cast(reference.dataP, ctypes.POINTER(DATA_STRUCT)).contents.text` (could store the cast pointer in an additional variable to avoid doing (writing) it multiple times)

Comment: The printed result after casting is (as before) 'dataP.contents.text: <__main__.LP_c_char_Array_41 object at 0x00000000028123C0>' Any other idea? (trying to print '...contents.text.value/raw' reports AttributeError: 'LP_c_char_Array_41' object has no attribute 'raw' )

Comment: You're not paying attention to details. It's ***restype***. The error is missing from the question (please add it). Also the *\_\_main\_\_.LP\_c\_char\_Array\_41* form the error in the comment (and the last question edit), tells me that you actually **didn't do *#1.***. Also I didn;t understand the compiler note. Why do you need a compiler if you already have the *.dll* and *Python*?

Comment: Thank you @CristiFati, for your patience, your solution works!!! :-) To answer your question - the proprietary .dll has more complicated structure, so to make people easier to help me here I created my own simplified .dll. After solving this problem I will of course use the ctypes to directly access the proprietary dll.

Comment: Aaa *OK*, so you used the compiler to create an [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Nice!. Bear in mind that *Python* is built with another compiler (https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers), and sometimes, mixing compilers might raise additional issues (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51230954/tdm-gcc-compiled-win32x64-dll-cannot-be-loaded-in-python-3-6-but-can-when-using).